# How to change true to false __N_SSG in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to change pageProps inside of  __N_SSG parameter true to false or remove pageProps. Because I generated build time multiple pages. I manual changed true to false, But If I take another build again want to change manually true to false, can you change runtime. could you please solve this issues. see below image.
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the `__N_SSG` value? Everything under the `__NEXT_DATA__` script is automatically generated by Next.js and is [required for proper React hydration](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13418#discussioncomment-103456) on the client. I would recommend you didn't change the data there even if you can.

Answer (score 0):

According to **Nextjs** support, [one should not rely on this API nor try to modify it directly](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12558).

> This is a private field (mind the double underscore) used by Next.js to know the page needs its static data fetched on client-side transition.
>
> You cannot rely on it, as we've already renamed it a few times and do not plan on making it a public API. We may even remove it in the future.

So... refrain from doing anything at that level, and rather solve the issue at the "page" level, by choosing ***static page generation***, ***server-side page generation*** or any other option offered by **Nextjs** at the time you're reading this.